# I have absolutely no access to any of my files

Tags: permissions, files, root

I had to reinstall Ubuntu due to an issue with the menus and after installing it and updating everything I have absolutely no access to anything even though I am the administrator account.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please provide further information on what you mean by you not having access and any errors messages which you have encountered, to better help us help you.

Comment: All of the files are locked in the harddrive. I have access to most of my home folder though.

Comment: So which directories are you not able to access, and are you just not able to write to the contents, or are you fully even unable to list the contents?

Comment: I can list the contents but i cant go into any of the files. except the root directory of the hard drive. I can also obviously access applications.

Comment: If you go into one of these folders by using the `cd` command in Terminal and then you execute the command: `ls -al`. What is the output?

Comment: It says everything is owned by root in the / folder I could put it in the comment because it was too  long.

Comment: Yes, root is different than administrator account. Your account is administrator level, meaning you can adjust settings and what-not, but you are not "root" user. If you want gui access to these files, you can open a terminal and type `sudo nautilus`. This will run Nautilus (the file manager) as root.

Comment: Unable to create a required folder. Please create the following folder, or set permissions such that it can be created:
/root/.config/nautilus                                                                                                 After trying to edit the permissions I was told it wasn’t allowed to change and then crashed. How can I change my administrative user to be a root user

Comment: You should NOT use nautilus with `sudo`. [More information in this part of the chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20216414#20216414)

Comment: OK... So how will I fix this problem.. I don’t know how to make my user root and I cant change the permissions.

Comment: Information can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#root_account) on how to become root (although extremely inadvisable), and read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) for information on the `chmod` command which allows you to change the permissions for folders and files.

Comment: Ok so I understand how to use chmod but how would I make it so I can get access to every files without you know going through every file with the command

Answer (score 0):

All files and directories except those in your home folder are owned by *root*, which is the "god"-user on your system. That you have an administrative account does just mean that you have the privilege to *get root rights* by using `sudo` for terminal programs or `gksu`/`gksudo`/`pkexec` for GUI programs.
So to have full access on the folders that are not your home, run your file manager (`nautilus` by default in Ubuntu) with `gksu`.
Or: If you install the file manager `nemo`, you also get the option "open as root..." in the context menu of every folder.

Please do not enable the root account, as this is a big security danger. And this default setting prevents you from messing up your system accidentally (a bit).